# PDF creation with page refresh

Tags: pdf, xpages

I have a page with a viewPanel and a dialog. When an item in the viewPanel is clicked, the dialog opens, prompting the user to make changes to that item, and offering them the option to generate a report of the item in PDF format.

At first,  I tried putting the PDF creation onto a button, as described here: http://www.eknori.de/2011-10-25/xpages-to-pdf-with-itext/ However, whenever the button is pressed, I get a "NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8" which seems to stem from the dojo JS. So currently I have an alternative whereby the button simply sets some sessionScope variables and opens a pdf.xsp XPage, where the variables are read back and the PDF is created.

The PDF gets created correctly, but it also means that the page that the user is on won't be refreshed to display their new change in the viewPanel. I've tried adding page redirects at the bottom of the XPage which creates the PDF, but with no luck.

So, how can I create a PDF and prompt a user to download it, but also refresh the page that they are currently on?

Answer (score 1):

Are you isseuing an partial refresh on the button to hide your dialog and to execute the code for pdf generation? If so you I think that there is your problem. What you could do is to do a partial refresh on the onClose() method of the dialog to refresh the viewpanel. In the clientside onunload method you could open a so called xAgent which renders the pdf for you in a new window (window.open(pdf.xsp?docid=xxx). Take a look here: [NotesIn9: 039 Creating PDF’s with XPages Part 2](http://notesin9.com/index.php/2012/01/10/notesin9-039-creating-pdfs-with-xpages-part-2/)

Of cours the problem with this approach is that when you have a button / image in yoru viewpanel row that displays if the report has been created is not shown because the xagent runs after the / during the time the viewpanel row is being refreshed.